# ¿Cuál es la etimología de "ganga"?

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos, animales

En el DLE aparece [**ganga**](https://dle.rae.es/ganga) como:

> 1. f. Ave del orden de las columbiformes, algo mayor que la tórtola  ...
>
> 2. f. Bien que se adquiere a un precio muy por debajo del que normalmente le corresponde.

¿Qué relación hay entre esas acepciomes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que, antiguamente, "ganga" se utilizaba en sentido figurado con dos significados opuestos: el actual ("cosa buena inesperada") y el contrario ("cosa sin provecho"). En el *Diccionario de la lengua castellana* de **1734** (consultable en [NTLLE](https://apps.rae.es/ntlle)) viene:

> GANGA. Analogicamente vale lo mismo que máula, ò cosa sin provecho ò util: y tal vez se toma en sentido contrario

La expresión "andar a caza de gangas" también viene en el diccionario de 1734 con dos significados opuestos:

> Andar à caça de *gangas*. Vale andar empeñado inutilmente en conseguir alguna cosa: y se toma también en sentido contrario: esto es pretendiendo conseguir ò hallar algo sin trabajo, ò sin costa: como quien se lo halla

[Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?ganga) considera que el significado "negativo" ("cosa sin provecho") se debe a que la ganga era muy difícil de cazar y su carne era muy dura. Etimologías de Chile atribuye el significado positivo ("cosa útil de bajo precio") a un uso irónico.

Parece que el uso irónico "positivo" era tan común que poco a poco se convirtió en el significado principal. A partir de **1803**, los diccionarios incluyen solo el significado positivo:

> GANGA. met. Qualquiera cosa apreciable que se adquiere a poca costa, ó con poco trabajo.

El significado negativo aparece ya solo en la expresión "buena ganga es esa", a veces calificada como "irónica":

> BUENA GANGA ES ESA. expr. con que se significa no ser cosa de provecho lo que se consigue ó pretende.

A partir de **1901**, el significado "negativo" deja de ser mencionado en todos los diccionarios, aunque algunos siguen mencionándolo.

En resumen, parece que "ganga" se usaba inicialmente con el significado de "cosa sin provecho" debido a la dureza de la carne del ave. Como era tan común usar la palabra irónicamente con el significado contrario ("cosa apreciable de bajo precio"), este significaco irónico desplazó al original, y los diccionarios empezaron a llamar "sentido irónico" al significado negativo.

Comment: En minería y metalurgia, *ganga* tiene un significado muy específico, el conjunto de minerales extraídos con la mena sin interés económico.

Answer (score 0):

Ganga se refiere al material que acompaña al mineral bruto cuando es extraído de una mina. Al limpiar el metal extraído, la ganga es descartada como elemento inútil.

Se trata de una palabra diferente del homónimo ganga ‘gallináceo semejante a una perdiz’, que es de otra etimología.

Ganga, con el sentido que estudiamos hoy, aparece en nuestra lengua en el siglo XIX, proveniente del francés gangue, del mismo significado, que a su vez se deriva del alemán gang ‘filón de una mina.

De Ricardo Sosa.

Espero te haya servido. Saludos.

Diego M.